# WPF: How to populate combobox with enum in Xaml

Tags: wpf, enums, combobox

I know there are several ways to do it, but I would like to make it even easier if possible because I have a lot of comboboxes to bind in this way. There is a suggestion using ObjectDataProvider [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/BindEnumValues.html). The problem is that I have to create a resource entry for each enum and that's a lot. So far, I have been using the code-behind way because it's much shorter:

```
cmb.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyTypes));
```

I'm wondering if an equivalent can be produced in Xaml. I thought we could archive this by using a converter. We could convert the type to an array and then bind the array to combobox' ItemsSource. But I got stuck on how to specify my enum to the converter. Here is my code:

My enum:

```
public enum MyTypes { Type1, Type2, Type3 };
```

This is my converter:

```
public class EnumToArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(value.GetType());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null; // I don't care about this
    }
}
```

My Xaml Resource:

```
<lib:EnumToArrayConverter x:Key="E2A"/>
```

Here is how to use it:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding MyType}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTypes, Converter={StaticResource E2A}}"/>
```

So, my question is how to specify my enum "MyTypes" to the converter. I also tried to prepend namespace, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be better off with a [MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx), like [this one](http://summergoat.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/enum-getvalues-markup-extension/).

Comment: Thanks very much for the TIP. It works great! Just curious: Why can't I pass {x:Type MyTypes} to the converter? or what is the right syntax for doing that?

Comment: Actually, you can :-) Just read Meleak's post, but that's not really the best way to do it in WPF.

Comment: You are right. So, MarkupExtension is more powerful. Is it right to say MarkupExtension could replace IValueConverter?

Comment: No, not at all. The IValueConverter is used to convert values as they pass through a Binding. The MarkupExtension allows you to provide a "value" using XAML. For example, if you have a property bound to a Text property, you could use an IValueConverter to make the string upper case.

Comment: Downvoted because the linked article does not actually work - it is incomplete and does not show a complete code set for implementation. Further, implementing it in VS2015 results in a syntax error stating that the first open curly brace in the ItemsSource binding is unexpected - the code is likely no longer valid for newer MarkupExpression syntax. Would suggest posting a working solution here for contemporary VS.

Answer (score 4):

CodeNaked posts a great way of doing this

For your approach to work you can change the converter to `Enum.GetValues(value as Type)` and use the `x:Type` syntax as Source for the Binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Type local:MyValues},
                      Converter={StaticResource EnumToArrayConverter}}"
```

**EnumToArrayConverter**

```
public class EnumToArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(value as Type);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null; // I don't care about this
    }
}
```