# Populating GridVIewComboBox with Enum

Tags: wpf

I have a grid such that when I load the grid it's populated with "Active Records". Every column populates properly except the enum column, the enum colkumn is blank. The combobox I can click into and it is populated with the enums.

If I can get some help to setting the enum to display correctly please.

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Width="100" 
                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Occurence}"                         
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Type accounts:Insurance+Occurences}, Converter={StaticResource EnumToArrayConverter}}">
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Rate" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Rate, StringFormat='#,##0.#0'}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Rate, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='#,##0.#0', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>


<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyEnumDataProvider" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="accounts:InsuranceTypes"></x:Type>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

EnumToArrayConverter is from [WPF: How to populate combobox with enum in Xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274423/wpf-how-to-populate-combobox-with-enum-in-xaml)

The Rates column populates but the enum column remains empty.

Comment: does your binding work ? is your converter.convert called ?

Comment: Yes, i've set a breakpoint inside EnumToArrrayConverter and it gets hit.

Comment: I just checked my code, I am not using this approach but mine works.. its using ObjectDataProvider.. lemme know if you need sample

Comment: Sure that would be great!

Comment: posted as answer have a look and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will solve it using object data provider

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                x:Key="EnumDataProvider">
<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    <x:Type TypeName="local:SomeENUM" />
</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
```

then use data column and override its template to have combobox in it and bind combo box like this

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumDataProvider}}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding selectedEnum}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: our methods are identical actually :P I forgot to add in my ObjectDataProvider. the only difference is I'm using telerik's combo box and instead of SelectedItem it's DatamemberBinding. But still no go =(

Comment: well then I would suggest you to use data column and make it have a combobox inside, I am not sure how radcomboboxcolumn works...

Comment: see the changed code, it now alters cell template of GridViewDataColumn